# If I have two cyberarms, do I need an additional modification to interact with AR?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I cannot find this answer anywhere in the RAW.

If I have two cyberarms (whole or partial, doesn't matter), do I need some kind of additional modification to interact with augmented reality?

Answer (score 7):

To use Augmented Reality, you need a **commlink**. "Internet Access" if you want an analogy to today's world.

And you need a way to have your commlink display information to you, although that is already included with every commlink package sold in Shadowrun <sup>(1)</sup>. You can probably buy upgrades in many shapes and forms. There are integrated commlinks and headware that already have commlinks implanted.

But none of this has anything to do with cyber limbs like arms or legs. It's *augmented* reality, there is nothing to physically touch.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> *if you are playing a future version or using a future expansion book, just do a quick check for this yourself in the future book, SR has a tendency to complicate the simple things over time or with more books*

Comment: Can they replicate the AR glove functionality as listed in SR5 p. 439?

Comment: They don't say so, so I guess no. I have never seen an addon/option for arms or hands to include AR gloves. You will just have to use regular AR gloves. That said, I don't think any character of mine ever *had* AR gloves, because they are about as useful as a TV today... while everybody has one, it's not like you need it for a job or put it on your CV.

Comment: @nvoigt The proper term, per pg. 438 of the Core Rulebook, is "Commlink".

Comment: @Codeacula Oh, it is... ok cool, I thought that was just my translated book. I'll change it back. I didn't even see you edited it, I thought I had used my German spelling.

Comment: @nvoigt I didn't want to step on your toes by editing it again :D

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, you do.

Rules-As-Written does not allocate for cyberarms to interact with the Matrix aside from providing wireless bonuses that I can find. You would need to purchase a set of AR Gloves to fit over your hands, just like those packing meat would.

As a GM, I would likely wave it away. Motion tracking in the real world already allows for us to interact with objects in AR, so it makes sense you could do it in Sixth World. I wouldn't allow them to retain the other benefits (force-feedback and being able to read object's properties), though.